# I get script error on the line 0 in p5js editor

Tags: javascript

[p5js editor enviroment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cft7t.png)
hello I'm a beginner programmer and I wanted to play around a little bit, but right at the start I get this error, I'm following everything as in the reference, so I don't really get what's the problem, can anyone explain to me what's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing the img variable to something else like img123.
As the error msg shows there is already a variable with the same name.